# swisscom cloudfoundry: scaling up DB size

Tags: php, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I have a MariaDB for my PHP BP on the Swisscom CloudFoundry Appcloud and was wondering if I can upscale that service from small to medium without having to create a new service, migrate the data and re-binding the app.

Grtnx,
Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for "cloud foundry change service instance" I found a section of the [open source documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/managing-services.html#update_service) which says:

> By updating the service plan for an instance, users can effectively upgrade and downgrade their service instance to other service plans. Though the platform and CLI now support this feature, services must expressly implement support for it so not all services will. Further, a service might support updating between some plans but not others (e.g., a service might support updating a plan where only a logical change is required, but not where data migration is necessary).

So it sounds like it could be possible in principle, but unlikely because it would involve a data migration, so the Swisscom MariaDB service would have to be fairly exceptional.  The documentation on the [Swisscom MariaDB service](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/services/offerings/mariadb.html) doesn't seem to settle the answer one way or another.

You could try it yourself (on a separate test app to be safe):

```
cf update-service SERVICE_INSTANCE [-p NEW_PLAN] [-c PARAMETERS_AS_JSON] [-t TAGS]
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! You're right, in essence that's how it would be done, but CF correctly points out, that: Server error, status code: 400, error code: 110004, message: The service does not support changing plans.

Answer (score 1):

Small clarification from the source - Swisscom Application Cloud Team:

Indeed the feature of changing service plan is not currently supported by our platform for none of our services. We have it on our roadmap (service up-scaling). More rapidly we should release more advanced backup management features that should make such operations easier to perform manually.

kind regards

Michal